# position sticky top and bottom page layout?

Tags: html, css, sticky

Is there a way to update [**this gist**](https://gist.run/?id=5b0e670832c94718857914bf713d28e3) such that the `<nav>` element sticks to `bottom:16px` until the `<footer>` pushes it up when the user scrolls to the bottom of the page?

I'm trying to find a way to keep the bottom of the `<nav>` element 16px from the top of the footer (or the bottom of the viewport when the footer is scrolled outside the viewport). In other words, I want the bottom of the nav element and footer to behave just like the top of the nav element and the header are behaving in my gist.

The `max-height: calc(100vh - 50px - 16px - 16px);` in my gist is just a workaround. Really the max-height depends on whether the header and/or footer are in the viewport.

Here's a screenshot that shows what I'm attempting to fix:

[image: nav issue]

The current behavior of the top of the `<nav>` element should be preserved. It is 16px from the top of the `<header>` (or the top of the viewport when the header is outside the viewport).

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.page-header, .page-footer {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.page-layout {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: flex-start;
  margin: 16px 0;
}

.page-layout-nav, .page-layout-main, .page-layout-aside {
  border: 1px dotted;
}

.page-layout-nav {
  order: 0;
  width: calc(25% - 16px);
}

.page-layout-main {
  order: 1;
  width: 50%;
}

.page-layout-aside {
  order: 2;
  width: calc(25% - 16px);
}

.page-layout-nav, .page-layout-aside {
  position: sticky;
  top: 16px;
  bottom: 16px;
  overflow: auto;
  max-height: calc(100vh - 50px - 16px - 16px); /* not quite right... */
}
```

```html
<header class="page-header">
  Contoso
</header>
<div class="page-layout">
  <main class="page-layout-main">
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
    <p>lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  </p>
    <h2>Foo</h2>
    <p>lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  </p>
    <h2>Bar</h2>
    <p>lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  </p>
    <h2>Foo</h2>
    <p>lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  </p>
    <h2>Bar</h2>
    <p>lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  </p>
  </main>

  <nav class="page-layout-nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <aside class="page-layout-aside">
    <h2>In this article</h2>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
    </ul>
  </aside>
</div>

<footer class="page-footer">
  foo bar baz
</footer>
```

Comment: Did you ever manage to solve this? I'm trying to do something similar... Thanks!

Comment: no - hasn't been solved

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `align-self:flex-end` on that element to allow sticking at the bottom.

[Updated gist](https://gist.run/?id=1a977db2bd81be7b1f2bcc35df527ed0)

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.page-header, .page-footer {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.page-layout {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 16px 0;
}

.page-layout-nav, .page-layout-main, .page-layout-aside {
  border: 1px dotted;
}

.page-layout-nav {
  order: 0;
  width: calc(25% - 16px);
  align-self: flex-end;
}

.page-layout-main {
  order: 1;
  width: 50%;
}

.page-layout-aside {
  order: 2;
  width: calc(25% - 16px);
  align-self: flex-start;
}

.page-layout-nav, .page-layout-aside {
  position: sticky;
  top:16px;
  bottom: 16px;
  overflow: auto;
  max-height: calc(100vh - 50px - 16px - 16px); /* not quite right... */
}
```

```html
<header class="page-header">
  Contoso
</header>
<div class="page-layout">
  <main class="page-layout-main">
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
    <p>lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  </p>
    <h2>Foo</h2>
    <p>lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  </p>
    <h2>Bar</h2>
    <p>lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  </p>
    <h2>Foo</h2>
    <p>lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  </p>
    <h2>Bar</h2>
    <p>lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  </p>
  </main>

  <nav class="page-layout-nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <aside class="page-layout-aside">
    <h2>In this article</h2>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
    </ul>
  </aside>
</div>

<footer class="page-footer">
  foo bar baz
</footer>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Looks promising- I've edited my question to try to make it more clear what I'm attempting to do. I want to keep the bottom of the <nav> element 16px from the top of the footer (or the bottom of the viewport when the footer is scrolled outside the viewport).

Comment: @JeremyDanyow isn't that what is happening in the snippet ?

Comment: Yes- my fault, I've added further clarification to my question. Apologies!
I want to preserve the current behavior of the top of the `<nav>` element. It is 16px from the top of the `<header>` (or the top of the viewport when the header is outside the viewport).  In other words how do I make the bottom of the nav element behave the same way the top of the nav element is behaving.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add `margin-top:auto` to the nav :

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.page-header, .page-footer {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.page-layout {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: flex-start;
  margin: 16px 0;
}

.page-layout-nav, .page-layout-main, .page-layout-aside {
  border: 1px dotted;
}

.page-layout-nav {
  order: 0;
  width: calc(25% - 16px);
  margin-top:auto;
}

.page-layout-main {
  order: 1;
  width: 50%;
}

.page-layout-aside {
  order: 2;
  width: calc(25% - 16px);
}

.page-layout-nav, .page-layout-aside {
  position: sticky;
  top: 16px;
  bottom: 16px;
  overflow: auto;
  max-height: calc(100vh - 50px - 16px - 16px); /* not quite right... */
}
```

```html
<header class="page-header">
  Contoso
</header>
<div class="page-layout">
  <main class="page-layout-main">
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
    <p>lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  </p>
    <h2>Foo</h2>
    <p>lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  </p>
    <h2>Bar</h2>
    <p>lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  </p>
    <h2>Foo</h2>
    <p>lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  </p>
    <h2>Bar</h2>
    <p>lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  lorem ipsum sumit dolar.  </p>
  </main>

  <nav class="page-layout-nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <aside class="page-layout-aside">
    <h2>In this article</h2>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
    </ul>
  </aside>
</div>

<footer class="page-footer">
  foo bar baz
</footer>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Looks promising- I've edited my question to try to make it more clear what I'm attempting to do. I want to keep the bottom of the <nav> element 16px from the top of the footer (or the bottom of the viewport when the footer is scrolled outside the viewport).

Comment: @JeremyDanyow ok, so we have to first remove your workaround and then try to find a solution ?