# position sticky top and bottom

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there a way to update [this gist](https://gist.run/?id=5b0e670832c94718857914bf713d28e3) such that the side menu nav extends to the bottom of the viewport during scroll, until it is pushed up by the footer? It should also maintain its current `position: sticky` behaviour of sticking to the top of the viewport.

Edit 1: yes this is a duplicate of the problem linked below, but the answers given in the linked post don't actually solve the problem!

Edit 2: to clarify: what I'm trying to achieve is simply a side-navigation element that takes up the full height available to it. As you scroll down the element should "stick" to the top of the viewport (this is what `position: sticky` with `top:0` does perfectly. Similarly, as you scroll down the *bottom* of the element should grow downward -- it should *stick* to the bottom of the viewport, until you scroll so far down that the footer starts pushing the element up (at which point it should shrink). Basically I want a side-nav that takes up as much space in the viewport as possible, but never expands outside the viewport. If it has inside it more content than can fit in the viewport, then this overflow should become scrollable -- but the entire element is always within the bounds of the viewport!

Edit 3: I've uploaded a [video to youtube](https://youtu.be/AZy7PZCuClY). See the top and bottom markers? That is *exactly* where I would like the top and and bottom of my side-nav element to be. Basically I'd like the element to always be sandwiched right between TOP and BOTTOM.

[This is basically a re-post of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47916402/position-sticky-top-and-bottom-page-layout) question... Sorry about that, but no answer was provided there, and I've been stuck on this for days.]

The effect I'm hoping for would sort of be like `position: sticky` with top *and* bottom trigger points... See screenshot below from the original post. I'm basically trying to build a side-nav like [this one on the gitbook site](https://docs.gitbook.com/).

Pure CSS would be awesome, but if JS is needed then that's fine too! Please help!

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [position sticky top and bottom page layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47916402/position-sticky-top-and-bottom-page-layout)

Comment: @pensum that post is exactly the problem I'm facing, but none of the responses solve the problem

Answer (score 2):

Edited: to affect divs on both left and right.

I'm uncertain of the effect you want as the [gitbook site](https://docs.gitbook.com/) has its left nav much shorter than the main content, whilst your left nav is much longer than the main content. Here's a go at what I think you are trying to achieve - with javascript.

*Edited to meet OP's clarification of requirements.

Change your css to

```
    .page-layout-nav,
    .page-layout-aside {
      position: sticky;
      top: 0px;
      bottom:1px;
      overflow: auto;
      height: 100vh;
    }
```

Then try using this script to adjust the height of the left nav during scroll.

```
    var doch = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight, window.innerHeight || 0);

    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
      var onav = document.getElementsByClassName('page-layout-nav')[0];
      var onavr = document.getElementsByClassName('page-layout-aside')[0];
      var doch = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight, window.innerHeight || 0);
      topspace = window.scrollY + doch - 16 - 50 - 2;
      onav.style.height = topspace + "px";
      onavr.style.height = topspace + "px";

    });

    function update() {
      var onav = document.getElementsByClassName('page-layout-nav')[0];
      var onavr = document.getElementsByClassName('page-layout-aside')[0];
      var ofooter = document.getElementsByClassName('page-footer')[0];
      var threshold = window.scrollY + doch + 16;
      var topspace = 0;
      if (window.scrollY < 16 + 50) {
        topspace = window.scrollY + doch - 16 - 50 - 2;
        onav.style.height = topspace + "px";
        onavr.style.height = topspace + "px";
      } else if (threshold >= ofooter.offsetTop) {
        onav.style.height = doch - threshold + ofooter.offsetTop + "px";
        onavr.style.height = doch - threshold + ofooter.offsetTop + "px";
      } else {
        onav.style.height = (doch - 1) + "px";
        onavr.style.height = (doch - 1) + "px";
      }

    }

    window.addEventListener('scroll', update);
```

Here's the full code with runnable result:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>GistRun</title>
  <style>
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    html,
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    
    .page-header,
    .page-footer {
      height: 50px;
      background-color: #ccc;
    }
    
    .page-layout {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
      align-items: flex-start;
      margin: 16px 0;
    }
    
    .page-layout-nav,
    .page-layout-main,
    .page-layout-aside {
      border: 1px dotted;
    }
    
    .page-layout-nav {
      order: 0;
      width: calc(25% - 16px);
    }
    
    .page-layout-main {
      order: 1;
      width: 50%;
    }
    
    .page-layout-aside {
      order: 2;
      width: calc(25% - 16px);
    }
    
    .page-layout-nav,
    .page-layout-aside {
      position: sticky;
      top: 0px;
      bottom:1px;
      overflow: auto;
      height: 100vh;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <header class="page-header">
    Contoso
  </header>
  
  <div class="page-layout">
    <main class="page-layout-main">
      <h1>Hello World</h1>
      <p>lorem ipsum sumit dolar. lorem ipsum sumit dolar. lorem ipsum sumit dolar. lorem ipsum sumit dolar. lorem ipsum sumit dolar. lorem ipsum sumit dolar. lorem ipsum sumit dolar. lorem ipsum sumit dolar. lorem ipsum sumit dolar. lorem ipsum sumit dolar.
        lorem ipsum sumit dolar. </p>
      <h2>Foo</h2>
      <p>lorem ipsum sumit dolar. lorem ipsum sumit dolar. lorem ipsum sumit dolar. lorem ipsum sumit dolar. lorem ipsum sumit dolar. lorem ipsum sumit dolar. lorem ipsum sumit dolar. lorem ipsum sumit dolar. lorem ipsum sumit dolar. lorem ipsum sumit dolar.
        lorem ipsum sumit dolar. </p>
      <h2>Bar</h2>
      <p>lorem ipsum sumit dolar. lorem ipsum sumit dolar. lorem ipsum sumit dolar. lorem ipsum sumit dolar. lorem ipsum sumit dolar. lorem ipsum sumit dolar. lorem ipsum sumit dolar. lorem ipsum sumit dolar. lorem ipsum sumit dolar. lorem ipsum sumit dolar.
        lorem ipsum sumit dolar. </p>
      <h2>Foo</h2>
      <p>lorem ipsum sumit dolar. lorem ipsum sumit dolar. lorem ipsum sumit dolar. lorem ipsum sumit dolar. lorem ipsum sumit dolar. lorem ipsum sumit dolar. lorem ipsum sumit dolar. lorem ipsum sumit dolar. lorem ipsum sumit dolar. lorem ipsum sumit dolar.
        lorem ipsum sumit dolar. </p>
      <h2>Bar</h2>
      <p>lorem ipsum sumit dolar. lorem ipsum sumit dolar. lorem ipsum sumit dolar. lorem ipsum sumit dolar. lorem ipsum sumit dolar. lorem ipsum sumit dolar. lorem ipsum sumit dolar. lorem ipsum sumit dolar. lorem ipsum sumit dolar. lorem ipsum sumit dolar.
        lorem ipsum sumit dolar. </p>
    </main>

    <nav class="page-layout-nav">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">1st foo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

    <aside class="page-layout-aside">
      <h2>In this article</h2>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">foo</a></li>
      </ul>
    </aside>
  </div>

  <footer class="page-footer">
    foo bar baz
  </footer>

  <script>
    var doch = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight, window.innerHeight || 0);

    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
      var onav = document.getElementsByClassName('page-layout-nav')[0];
      var onavr = document.getElementsByClassName('page-layout-aside')[0];
      var doch = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight, window.innerHeight || 0);
      topspace = window.scrollY + doch - 16 - 50 - 2;
      onav.style.height = topspace + "px";
      onavr.style.height = topspace + "px";

    });

    function update() {
      var onav = document.getElementsByClassName('page-layout-nav')[0];
      var onavr = document.getElementsByClassName('page-layout-aside')[0];
      var ofooter = document.getElementsByClassName('page-footer')[0];
      var threshold = window.scrollY + doch + 16;
      var topspace = 0;
      if (window.scrollY < 16 + 50) {
        topspace = window.scrollY + doch - 16 - 50 - 2;
        onav.style.height = topspace + "px";
        onavr.style.height = topspace + "px";
      } else if (threshold >= ofooter.offsetTop) {
        onav.style.height = doch - threshold + ofooter.offsetTop + "px";
        onavr.style.height = doch - threshold + ofooter.offsetTop + "px";
      } else {
        onav.style.height = (doch - 1) + "px";
        onavr.style.height = (doch - 1) + "px";
      }

    }

    window.addEventListener('scroll', update);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Sorry I wasn't very clear, I will edit the question. Your response doesn't quite do what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Ok. I edited my answer. Basically change the heights such that the left nav fills up the whole height viewport. Take a look and let me know if that is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you... But it seems the element extends beyond the viewport when scrolled all the way up. I'm hoping to always have the element fully within the viewport.

Comment: Ok. Fixed. Forgot to consider the 16 margin between the footer and nav. Or am I still understanding your requirement wrongly??

Comment: Added a youtube video!

Comment: The element extends beyond the viewport for me. It goes down past the bottom of the viewport when scrolled all the way up?

Comment: Hmm.. what browser are you using?

Comment: ok. Sorry I kept thinking your scroll up as "down", (I am using the reverse scroll). I see your problem now. I have edited the code. Hopefully now it is what you want..

Comment: hey, sorry, it looks good in the preview window thing, but when I go full screen it doesn't expand to fill the viewport height.

Comment: I found a solution that I think is decent. I will post it in a bit.

Comment: I believe it doesn't expand to fill the viewport height because you are using stackoverflow's "Run code snippet" and "Full Page"? Stackoverflow embeds it in an iframe and so the styles and calculations are different. I believe if you run it on a browser on a proper page it should work and achieve the effect you want. If not, I really want to know what browser you are using as I cannot reproduce your error.

Comment: You're right, if I run it in a full browser window it does what I've described, albeit with some jumpiness when the footer comes into the viewport. The solution I've come to is to use a top and bottom `position:sticky` elements and pin the div to them...

Comment: Ok! Great you found your solution. Could you post it here so everyone can learn from it please? I would love to learn a css solution for this too. Thanks!